# Why does my ADC -> TIM -> DMA driver work for a bit, then freeze up, then continue working again?

Tags: stm32, adc, dma, mbed

This is difficult to describe, but basically my DMA ADC stream will give me correct readings for lets say 10 seconds, then gets "locked up" / outputs static values that do not change (when they should), and then randomly start "working" again. ‍♂️

The rest of the peripherals (I2C, SPI, GPIO etc.) continue to work just fine, and the program never crashes - which is really making me scratch my head

I will admit that this is the first real implementation of DMA I have ever done, but I want to say I have all the configuration correct.

My configuration driver is below. The configuration is to trigger ADC reads via TIM3 for 8 ADC channels, and then funnel those readings into a DMA buffer.

Anyone have a clue what could be going on? Does the MCU perhaps not have enough time to read all the ADC Channels and thus... idk just give up? I am running this code along side the MBE framework, which honestly should not give me any problems, but I do have a lot of other interupts occuring outside of the ADC reads - but nothing I would deem as high frequency.

**MCU: STM32F446RET**

````
#include "MultiChanADC.h"

#define ADC_DMA_BUFF_SIZE 8

ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc1;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_adc1;
TIM_HandleTypeDef htim3;

uint16_t DMA_ADC_BUFFER[ADC_DMA_BUFF_SIZE];

void multi_chan_adc_init() {
    MX_DMA_Init();
    MX_ADC1_Init();
    MX_TIM3_Init();
}

void multi_chan_adc_start() {
    HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim3);
    HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc1, (uint32_t *)DMA_ADC_BUFFER, ADC_DMA_BUFF_SIZE);
}

/**
  * @brief ADC1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
void MX_ADC1_Init(void)
{

    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
    /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_MspInit 0 */

    /* USER CODE END ADC1_MspInit 0 */
    /* Peripheral clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_ADC1_CLK_ENABLE();

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
    /**ADC1 GPIO Configuration
  PA4     ------> ADC1_IN4
  PA5     ------> ADC1_IN5
  PA6     ------> ADC1_IN6
  PA7     ------> ADC1_IN7
  PC4     ------> ADC1_IN14
  PC5     ------> ADC1_IN15
  PB0     ------> ADC1_IN8
  PB1     ------> ADC1_IN9
  */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_4 | GPIO_PIN_5 | GPIO_PIN_6 | GPIO_PIN_7;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_4 | GPIO_PIN_5;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0 | GPIO_PIN_1;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /* ADC1 DMA Init */
    /* ADC1 Init */
    hdma_adc1.Instance = DMA2_Stream0;
    hdma_adc1.Init.Channel = DMA_CHANNEL_0;
    hdma_adc1.Init.Direction = DMA_PERIPH_TO_MEMORY;
    hdma_adc1.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
    hdma_adc1.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
    hdma_adc1.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_HALFWORD;
    hdma_adc1.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_HALFWORD;
    hdma_adc1.Init.Mode = DMA_CIRCULAR;
    hdma_adc1.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_LOW;
    hdma_adc1.Init.FIFOMode = DMA_FIFOMODE_DISABLE;
    HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_adc1);

    __HAL_LINKDMA(&hadc1, DMA_Handle, hdma_adc1);

    ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};

    /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 1 */
    /**
 * NOTE: Important to set EOCSelection to "EOC Flag at the end of all converions" if you want to continuously read the ADC, otherwise
 *       the ADC will only do a single conversion 
*/
    /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 1 */
    /** Configure the global features of the ADC (Clock, Resolution, Data Alignment and number of conversion)
*/
    hadc1.Instance = ADC1;
    hadc1.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_SYNC_PCLK_DIV2;
    hadc1.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B;
    hadc1.Init.ScanConvMode = ENABLE;
    hadc1.Init.ContinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
    hadc1.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
    hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_RISING;
    hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONV_T3_TRGO;
    hadc1.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
    hadc1.Init.NbrOfConversion = 8;
    hadc1.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = ENABLE;
    hadc1.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SEQ_CONV;
    HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc1);

    /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
*/
    sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_6;
    sConfig.Rank = 1;
    sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_15CYCLES;
    HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig);

    /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
*/
    sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_7;
    sConfig.Rank = 2;
    HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig);

    /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
*/
    sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_15;
    sConfig.Rank = 3;
    HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig);

    /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
*/
    sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_14;
    sConfig.Rank = 4;
    HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig);

    /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
*/
    sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_4;
    sConfig.Rank = 5;
    HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig);

    /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
*/
    sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_5;
    sConfig.Rank = 6;
    HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig);

    /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
*/
    sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_8;
    sConfig.Rank = 7;
    HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig);

    /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
*/
    sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_9;
    sConfig.Rank = 8;
    HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig);
}

/**
  * @brief TIM3 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
void MX_TIM3_Init(void)
{
    __HAL_RCC_TIM3_CLK_ENABLE();

    TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = {0};
    TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};

    htim3.Instance = TIM3;
    htim3.Init.Prescaler = 100;
    htim3.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
    htim3.Init.Period = 2000;
    htim3.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
    htim3.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
    HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim3);

    sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
    HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim3, &sClockSourceConfig);

    sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_UPDATE;
    sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
    HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim3, &sMasterConfig);
}

/**
  * Enable DMA controller clock
  */
void MX_DMA_Init(void)
{

    /* DMA controller clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_DMA2_CLK_ENABLE();

    /* DMA interrupt init */
    /* DMA2_Stream0_IRQn interrupt configuration */
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA2_Stream0_IRQn, 0, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA2_Stream0_IRQn);
}

/**
 * @brief Overload this function in user code
*/
__WEAK void ADC1_DMA_Callback(uint16_t values[]) {
    // function to be overloaded in main program 
}

/**
  * @brief This function handles DMA2 stream0 global interrupt.
  * NOTE: This must be declared when using an interupt peripheral.
  * When there is an interrupt for which no handler exists, "Default_Handler" will be called and put the system in an inifinite loop
  */
extern "C" void DMA2_Stream0_IRQHandler(void)
{
    HAL_DMA_IRQHandler(&hdma_adc1);
}

/**
  * @brief  Regular conversion complete callback in non blocking mode 
  * @param  hadc pointer to a ADC_HandleTypeDef structure that contains
  *         the configuration information for the specified ADC.
  * @retval None
  */
extern "C" void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef *hadc)
{
    if (hadc->Instance == ADC1)
    {
        ADC1_DMA_Callback(DMA_ADC_BUFFER);
    }
}

```
````

Comment: Which STM micro are you using?

Comment: ahh forgot that - stm32f446ret

Comment: How can you tell it stops working? You sure you're not having readout aliasing?

Comment: @Jeroen3 not sure I know what readout aliasing is. It isn't exactly not working, it works for a short period of time, then stops and freezes on the last accurate reading for a short period of time, then starts working again

Comment: The code you provided does not show any means of getting the data out. So how do you know it's not working right? Looking at the memory through the debugger? That's a slow asynchronous method with variable timing. Prone to aliasing.

Comment: @Jeroen3 the driver works as expected when I run it in an isolated project, without MBED. But I am trying to implement it along side the MBED framework - and when I try and do that I experience this behavior. As I mentioned in another comment, maybe the MBED RTOS has something to do with it?

Comment: The DMA and ADC are hardware. They work regardless of any other software. They are also not halted on breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Read the errata sheet of your microcontroller.

There might be a silicon bug that prevents that peripheral to work properly.

In 2010 I had a problem with an STM8S microcontroller that once in a while, without reason, reset itself.
Years later, an STM's FAE told me that there was a Silicon bug in that chip.

I see here symptoms of a Silicon bug.

I would do the following:

1. Turn off DMA
2. Use a timer that periodically fires an interrupt and then start an ADC conversion.
3. Try first an interrupt driven ADC conversion where an interrupt is fired at the end of conversion. If it works fine then you are all set. If you face problems, use polled ADC conversion.

Comment: There is only a DMA related silicon error related to writing to the DAC

Comment: So the reason I am confident this isn't a silicon bug is that I have tested the driver in a pure C environment and it works as it should. I am trying to implement it alongside the MBED framework, which I believe so far is the culprit. I also tested it in a different C++ build and it works just fine. Perhaps the MBED RTOS could be setting the ADC Reads as a low priority? I dont know... Tricky.

Comment: Frameworks will add